# Discord.js: AbortError: request aborted

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

This is the code I implemented according to the discord.js guide:

```
//Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({
    restRequestTimeout: 60000,// change the timeout to 1 minute
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]
});

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
// We use 'c' for the event parameter to keep it separate from the already defined 'client'
client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});

// Log in to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

However, running the command 'node index.js' will result in the following error:

```
[AbortError]: Request aborted
    at abort (C:\Users\Jerrywweng\Desktop\discord-bot-test\node_modules\undici\lib\api\abort-signal.js:10:18)  
    at self.<computed> (C:\Users\Jerrywweng\Desktop\discord-bot-test\node_modules\undici\lib\api\abort-signal.js:29:5)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:758:20)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:700:26)
    at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:314:10)
    at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:332:5)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jerrywweng\Desktop\discord-bot-test\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:778:73)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  code: 'UND_ERR_ABORTED'
}
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens due to a failure when requesting to the Discord API. So this is most likely a connection issue, make sure you're not using a vpn or proxy and have a stable internet connection. If you think your connection is fine, then it's most likely a problem with Discord API, just try again later

Answer (score 0):

The connection being a reason in my case is false
upload speed 1.5gig
download 400mb